# How to Access html generated by Javascript with htmlunit?

Tags: java, maven, htmlunit

I need to access the rendered html that was generated by javascript. Like the html that is generated by javascript can be seen by inspect but I will be not available in viewsource of the page. So I need to get that html. I am trying with htmlunit.

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*;
    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */

    /**
     *
     * @author biznis
     */


        public class JsoupImageEx {

            public static void main(String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF); /* comment out to turn off annoying htmlunit warnings*/ 

            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            String url = "";
            System.out.println("Loading page now: "+url);
            HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30 * 1000); /* will wait JavaScript to execute up to 30s */

            String pageAsXml = page.asXml();
            System.out.println(pageAsXml);

            }
        }
```

using html unit 2.12 maven dependencies

I am getting exception

Output:

```
 Loading page now: 
    Exception in thread "main" ======= EXCEPTION START ========
    EcmaError: lineNumber=[2] column=[0] lineSource=[<no source>] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[https://inapi.ankiti.com/api/mms.bulksms101.com/www/parts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js?field=content] message=[TypeError: Cannot find function addEventListener in object [object HTMLDocument]. (https://inapi.ankiti.com/api/mms.bulksms101.com/www/parts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js?field=content#2)]
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function addEventListener in object [object HTMLDocument]. (https://inapi.ankiti.com/api/mms.bulksms101.com/www/parts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js?field=content#2)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:669)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:601)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:555)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:1082)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:399)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:260)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:276)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:676)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:635)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
        at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
        at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3074)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2041)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:918)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:892)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:241)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:187)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:268)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:156)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:434)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:309)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:374)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:359)
        at JsoupImageEx.main(JsoupImageEx.java:25)
    Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function addEventListener in object [object HTMLDocument]. (https://inapi.ankiti.com/api/mms.bulksms101.com/www/parts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js?field=content#2)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3603)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3587)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3608)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3624)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3688)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2207)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2189)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1333)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:275)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3031)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:546)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:654)
        ... 30 more
    Enclosed exception: 
    net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function addEventListener in object [object HTMLDocument]. (https://inapi.ankiti.com/api/mms.bulksms101.com/www/parts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js?field=content#2)

        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2207)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2189)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1333)
        at script(https://inapi.ankiti.com/api/mms.bulksms101.com/www/parts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js?field=content:2)
        at script(https://inapi.ankiti.com/api/mms.bulksms101.com/www/parts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js?field=content:2)
        at script(https://inapi.ankiti.com/api/mms.bulksms101.com/www/parts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js?field=content:2)
        at script(https://inapi.ankiti.com/api/mms.bulksms101.com/www/parts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js?field=content:2)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:275)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3031)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:546)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:654)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:601)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:555)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:1082)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:399)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:260)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:276)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:676)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:635)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
        at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
        at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3074)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2041)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:918)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:892)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:241)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:187)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:268)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:156)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:434)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:309)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:374)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:359)
        at JsoupImageEx.main(JsoupImageEx.java:25)
    ======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

I need to get that rendered outerhtml.

Comment: have you tried webClient .getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

Comment: yes you are right now im getting the output but as u can see u are using scripterror it will not print rendered html pleasetell me how can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

HtmlUnit 2.12 was released at Mar 6, 2013. Do you really expect that this version is still supported?
We are now at 2.28 and 2.29 is on the way. As far as i can see from a quick look at the [Changes](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/changes-report.html) this bug might be fixed in 2.14 but not sure.

So please update to the latest version. If you still have problems like this open an issue for HtmlUnit.

And finally copying thinks from Stackoverflow like

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF); /* comment out to turn off annoying htmlunit warnings*/
```

is not the best idea at all. You are hunting for a bug and disabling the whole log. Usually the log is there to help you and others to provide useful info to find the problems.

Comment: or either how can i use document.body.outerhtml() in jsoup